# Discard git commit without rollback file

Tags: git

I have a Git repo contains some large dataset, I accidently typed add . and cause git always trying to push the whole dataset on to git server. I have worked half a year on this project without push anythong to the Github.

Now I want to discard this commit and only push the code I wrote. But the git not let me doing it without finish the last commit. I also don't want to loss the code I wrote.

How can I resolve it?

Git Status

```
hundred of lines for my previous commit

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Git Push

```
Enumerating objects: 2343, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2343/2343), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1795/1795), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size (2.00 GiB)error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)

send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (2341/2341), 2.60 GiB | 5.96 MiB/s, done.
Total 2341 (delta 574), reused 2208 (delta 543), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I want to try git rever, but it may delete my codes.

Comment: If the offending file was _added_ in the last commit, it's very simple to delete it on a _new_ commit to replace it: `git rm --cached the-offending-file; git commit --amend --no-edit`. That is, again, _if the file was added in the last commit_. If it was on a _previous_ commit, then more work has to be done to remove it, but it's not that hard.

Comment: _"I have worked half a year on this project without push anythong to the Github."_ Ooof, that's a very long time to go without a push; it's a risky thing to do.  Also, the error message you are getting indicates the size of the transfer is too large...

Comment: To go back one commit without losing files, you should be able to do `git reset HEAD^ --soft`, which will wind back your git history by a single commit while keeping all the files that were in that commit staged.  You can then unstage the files you want to remove and re-commit.

Comment: @HaoweiLou: was that file updated several times over several commits over this time span ? or do you just have to remove the file from one specific commit in the past ?

Comment: Unfortunately, "that file updated several times over several commits over this time span"

Comment: I'm trying to clone my repo into a new folder, and copy my codes from there, not sure if it will work

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool to help you do that : `git filter-repo` ([link to github page](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo)). Read the front page for instructions on how to install it.

There is a guide to do the exact thing you want [in the Examples section](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES) :

[Partial history rewrites](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_partial_history_rewrites)

> For example, to remove a file named extraneous.txt from the master branch:
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --invert-paths --path extraneous.txt --refs master
> ```

Comment: Once you have filter-repo setup, you can start with `git filter-repo --analyze` which provides reports including all files in the repo (even deleted files), sorted largest size first. Sometimes this is helpful to identify other large files in the repo that you can remove, especially those that were accidentally added and deleted in a later commit.